# js.erb is rendering text not JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

Having a strange issue trying to update search results via AJAX in rails in that rails is loading the js.erb in a `<pre>` tag at raw text on the page and not firing any js in that file.

in index controller

```
if request.format.js?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end
```

Form set to fire AJAX with remote: true

```
    = form_tag(search_path, id: "form", remote: true, :'data-type' => 'script') do
```

index.je.erb

```
alert('hello');
$("#results").innerHTML("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'results', locals: { results: @results } ) %>");
```

routes.rb

```
  match 'search', to:  'properties#index', via: :post, defaults: { format: 'js' }
```

In routes I have tried to force js from the form as previously it was JSON, but makes no difference.
From the logs, the controller is receiving the js request but i get this in CHrome debugger:

```
(index):69 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/javascript: "http://localhost:3000/search".
```

Sticking a `alert("Js is working")` works without issue so JS is there and firing

Im stuck, this should be working by now, is it something silly i have missed, or something new in Rails 5 i am not aware of?

If i can provide any more info to help you halp me please just ask!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK then. ´remote: true` is not enough it seems! It does seem to submit the ajax request to the controller, but the controller is determined that it is text.

adding

```
jQuery ->
  $('#form').on "change", ->
    $.ajax '/properties/index',
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'script'
    data: $('form').serialize()
```

and hyjacking the form submit into pure ajax seemed to fix it all!